Open Equivalence relation induces discrete topology on the quotient
Let $X$ be a topological space and $\sim$ an equivalence relation open as a subset of $X\times X$. I need to show that the quotient $X/\sim$ then has the discrete topology.
That it, I need to show that $\{[x]\}$ is open for every $x\in X$. I see that there are open sets $U,V$ such that $(x,x)\in U\times V \subset \sim$ and thus $x\in U \subset X$. Is this a helpful step and could you provide me with another hint to proceed?
My idea is to show that maybe $\pi^{-1}(\{[x]\})=U$ which would solve the problem by continuity of the projection map but I can not see why this should hold.


My idea is to show that maybe $\pi^{-1}(\{[x]\})=U$

That would be nice, but note that the introduction of $U$ involved an arbitrary choice. You can't hope for that to be true independent of the choice.
But you still want to prove that $\pi^{-1}(\{[x]\})$ (which is just $[x]$, by the way) is open. If $y\in [x]$, then you can choose an open neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ in $\sim$, just like you tried for $(x,x)$.
Maybe that is enough as a hint.
